# Google Vision Color extraction

Tags: python, image, colors, vision

I am trying to read the image properties from links stored in a csv with Google Vision and write the results back to a new column.

With an adapted script of a friend of mine, I managed to read the csv, to download the picture, send it to Google, to retrieve the results - but not to write them back to the csv.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv
import os
import urllib
import io
from google.cloud import vision
#from google.cloud.vision import types

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./CREDENTIALS/tourism-219409-61b527f98297.json"
vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()


# run with "python start.py <csv-file-path> <csv-header-row-url> <image path>"
# example
# python start.py ./destinations2.csv fotolink ./images

# ------------------
#   FUNCTIONS
# ------------------
def printInLine(data):
    sys.stdout.write(data)


def getCsvlHeaderIndexOfUrl(csvPath, csvHeaderRowUrl, delimit):
    index = None
    with open(csvPath, 'r', encoding='UTF8') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=delimit)
        interestingrows = [row for idx, row in enumerate(reader) if idx in (0, 0)]
        for row in interestingrows:
            for i, name in enumerate(row):
                if (name == csvHeaderRowUrl):
                    index = i
        print(interestingrows)                    
        print('found: ' + csvHeaderRowUrl + ' @ position: ' + str(index))
        return index


def getCsvlValueByHeaderindexAndLinenumber(csvPath, headerUrlIndex, lineNumber, delimit):
    print('headerUrlIndex')
    print(headerUrlIndex)
    print('---')
    value = None
    with open(csvPath, 'r', encoding='UTF8') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=delimit)
        interestingrows = [row for idx, row in enumerate(reader) if idx in (lineNumber, lineNumber)]
        print(interestingrows)
        value = interestingrows[0][headerUrlIndex]

        print('found: ' + value + ' @ lineNumber: ' + str(lineNumber))
        return value


def saveLabelsBackToCsvByIndex(csvPath, lineNumber, labelString):
    # print('labelString: ' + labelString + str(lineNumber))
    # with is like your try .. finally block in this case
    with open(csvPath, 'r', encoding='UTF8') as file:
        # read a list of lines into data
        data = file.readlines()
        line = data[lineNumber].strip().replace('\"', '') + labelString + '\n'
        # cleanup string
        # line = line.replace(';', '')


        # print ("Result: " + line)
        data[lineNumber] = line

        # write everything back
        with open(csvPath, 'w', encoding='UTF8') as file:
            file.writelines(data)
        print(' --> ' + labelString)


def downloadImage(url, imageStorePath, index):
    cleanUrl = url.replace('\"', '')

    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(cleanUrl)
    image = imageStorePath + '/' + str(index) + file_extension
    print(' --> ' + image)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(cleanUrl, image)
        return image
    except Exception:
        print('ERROR: downloadImage -->', url)
        pass
        # urllib.request.urlretrieve(cleanUrl, image)
        return None


def sendImageToGoogleVision(path):

    """Detects image properties in the file."""
    from google.cloud import vision
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.image_properties(image=image)
    props = response.image_properties_annotation
    print('Properties:')

    for color in props.dominant_colors.colors:
        print('fraction: {}'.format(color.pixel_fraction))
        print('\tr: {}'.format(color.color.red))
        print('\tg: {}'.format(color.color.green))
        print('\tb: {}'.format(color.color.blue))
        print('\ta: {}'.format(color.color.alpha))
# ------------------
#   START
# ------------------

# checking parameters
if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    printInLine('parameters not correct (should be 5): --> ')
    print(len(sys.argv))
    printInLine(' ... Quiting app')
    sys.exit()

# setting parameters if OK
csvPath = sys.argv[1]
csvHeaderRowUrl = sys.argv[2]
imageStorePath = sys.argv[3]
delimit = ';'

# parameters are OK
if (csvPath and csvHeaderRowUrl and imageStorePath):
    print("csvPath: " + csvPath + " csvHeaderRowUrl: " + csvHeaderRowUrl + " imageStorePath: " + imageStorePath)
    print('parameters OK ... starting...')

    # get index (position) of csv-header url
    headerUrlIndex = getCsvlHeaderIndexOfUrl(csvPath, csvHeaderRowUrl, delimit)
    # print('headerUrlIndex: ' + str(headerUrlIndex))
    # start counter with 1 (after header)
    numberOfLines = sum(1 for line in open(csvPath, 'r', encoding='UTF8'))
    # print('numberOfLines: ' + str(numberOfLines))

    # loop over each line in csv
    for i in range(1, numberOfLines):
        # row in csv
        lineNumber = i
        # get url from csv-file
        url = getCsvlValueByHeaderindexAndLinenumber(csvPath, headerUrlIndex, lineNumber, delimit)
        # download image and get path to stored file (filePath)
        filePath = downloadImage(url, imageStorePath, lineNumber)
        if filePath:
            # send image to vision and get colours
            labels = sendImageToGoogleVision(filePath)
            # build list of labels
            labelString = delimit

 #                                                      ------ This is where I need your help......


            saveLabelsBackToCsvByIndex(csvPath, lineNumber, labelString)

else:
    print('parameters missing ... Quiting app')
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution....

for color in props.dominant_colors.colors:
                labelString = labelString + ('fraction: {}'.format(color.pixel_fraction)) + delimit + ('\tr: {}'.format(color.color.red)) + delimit + ('\tg: {}'.format(color.color.green)) + ('\tb: {}'.format(color.color.blue)) + ('\ta: {}'.format(color.color.alpha))